# How to solve floating 0.01 value on percentage discount

Tags: php

I'm facing some troubles with .01 values at the end of calculation and i would like to ask if someone has passed trough this issue and can give me a hand to solve mine.

I have this situation:

```
$total = '319.00';
$discount = '99.00';
$percentage_discount = number_format((1+($discount/$total)) * 100 - 100, 2, '.', '');

echo $percentage_discount . " %<br>";
echo $discount . "<br>";
echo number_format($total * (1-($percentage_discount / 100)), 2, '.', ''); //echo total
```

Result:

```
31.03 %
99.00
220.01
```

The result i need is The right percentage to get the final total value with 220.00

I know that on Magento VAT calculation was a problem similar to this, the final decimals floating was an issue from the beginning and hard to solve, but maybe some experienced person has solves this.

Comment: It looks like you've run into a classical floating point rounding problem.  Maybe you'll get better results if you do all calculations in the minor currency unit (pennies, cents, etc) instead.  3103 instead of 31.03, etc.  Then only round to a floating point number on output.  Also, never round floating point numbers until you output them.  You're throwing away information every time you round a number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `number_format()` on `$persentage_discount`, i.e. leave it as is:

```
$percentage_discount = ((1 + ($discount / $total)) * 100 - 100);
```

Otherwhise you are making double round during calculations and final result is `220.0143` because of that. If you want to show `$persentage_discount` somewhere, use `printf()`.

**Update**: just simplify the task and separate displays from real calculations:

```
<?php
    $total = '319.00';
    $discount = '99.00';
    $percentage_discount = ($discount / $total) * 100;
    $final = $total * (1-($percentage_discount / 100));

    printf('%.2f<br>', $total);
    printf('%.2f<br>', $discount);
    printf('%.2f%%<br>', $percentage_discount);
    printf('%.2f<br>', $final); 
?>
```

output:

```
319.00
99.00
31.03%
220.00
```

Comment: You're right, removing number_format() calculate it exactly, but.. i need to bring it to 2 decimals and get the correct value, i mean the Discount need to be in 2 decimals.

Comment: You must separate displays from calculations. As I mention if you want to display the discount somewhere, use printf(), but leave proper value untouched.

Comment: The main issue is 31.03% on convert back to value it result 220.01, but if i do with 4 decimals all is right i mean 319 - 31.0345% = 219.9999

Comment: Just simplify calculations and separate them from displays - see the update.

Comment: Thanks a lot mitkosoft, your answer is right and correct, what is wrong is my device interpreter that calculate 220.01 at the end based on 31.03%, i works only with 2 decimals, and i think i need to find how it calculates the values and how round it to send from the begining the correct values, lets say not 31.03% and send 31.02%.

Comment: Never round floating point numbers until output!  You're just throwing precision away

Answer (score -3):

`intval()` will do the trick. try it and let me know

echo $new=number_format($total * (1-($percentage_discount / 100)), 2, '.', '')."
"; //echo total
echo intval($new);